# AddEventListener to SharePoint Modal window, so that parent window can execute a function, declared inside the Modal

Tags: sharepoint, modal-dialog, addeventlistener

The following code, included in *$(document).ready* of the modal window, does not work. Apparently the iframe of the SharePoint modal window has not yet been loaded into DOM, when the addEventListener fires out.
What would be the correct approach to handle this?

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
            if(event.data == "openpi");{
                alert(1)
            }
        });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is dialogReturnValueCallback option in SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog, you could get the value from dialog and then used in parent window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //******** Dialog with Data from Pop Up Starts Here ***********/
     function openDialogAndReceiveData(tUrl, tTitle) {
         var options = {
             url: tUrl,
             title: tTitle,
             dialogReturnValueCallback: onPopUpCloseCallBackWithData
         };
         SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
     }

     function onPopUpCloseCallBackWithData(result, returnValue) {
         if(result== SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)
         { 
             SP.UI.Status.removeAllStatus(true);
             var sId = SP.UI.Status.addStatus("Data successfully populated to text boxes from Pop-up");
             SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(sId, 'green');
             document.getElementById('<%= txtData1.ClientID %>').value = returnValue[0];
             document.getElementById('<%= txtData2.ClientID %>').value = returnValue[1];
         }else if(result== SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel)
         {
             SP.UI.Status.removeAllStatus(true);
             var sId = SP.UI.Status.addStatus("You have cancelled the Operation !!!");
             SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(sId, 'yellow');
         }
     }
     //******** Dialog with Data from Pop Up Ends Here ***********/
 </script>
```

[Check here for details](http://www.ashokraja.me/articles/How-to-pass-or-return-value-from-a-SharePoint-2013-Modal-Popup-Dialog-to-the-Base-Page)